Azure Availability test error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
I have created an Azure availability test in non-prod environments which is failing to connect to the web app. The URI for the API given in the test is correct, and is working correctly from POSTMAN.
But is failing in the alert test on Azure.
Error seen from the troubleshooting report:
DNS lookup succeeded. Resolved IP address(es):
10.123.125.63
Connection failed with IP address: 10.123.125.63
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::ffff:10.123.125.63]:443
Added the IP address under networking inbound traffic configuration for the Web App. Read through most of the Microsoft Azure documentation and still no luck.
How do I connect to the IP address? What steps should I take?
